# Set height of elements inside ScrollView relative to screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on a layout, which I want it to look like this:

[image: 1]

My current approach is the following:

1. I have ScrollView with a LinearLayout as its child (**blue**)
2. I set the elements inside the LinearLayout with `android:height = "0px"`
3. I adjust their height with `android:weight = "0.25"` (**yellow**) and `android:weight = "0.50"` (**orange**).

Anyway, what I really want is to set some elements inside the LinearLayout with a height relative to the screen size.

**Is there a way I can accomplish this using xml only?**

If not, is there any reference of suggested dp sizes that would match ~25% or ~50% of screen height in most devices?

Comment: Maybe use this library? https://android-arsenal.com/details/3/2054

Answer (score 0):

You can set the size of the elements like TextView, Button etc as the percentage of the total screen size.

You get the display size from the `WindowManager` and set the element height to be some fraction of it.
For example, second portion of your layout is 50%. You can put three element with 20%, 20% , 10% in that 50% easily. However following code may help you.

```
Button button = new Button (this);
android.view.Display display = ((android.view.WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay(); 
button.setHeight((int)(display.getHeight()*0.20));
```

Comment: Thanks, but. Do you think there is a way of achieving a similar result using XML only?

Comment: Sorry i didn't find anything in xml to achieve similar result. @SusyP